# Find $\lambda$ such that $f$ it is differentiable in zero and has a continuous derivative in zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

I am trying to solve this task

> Find $\lambda>0$ such that $f=\begin{cases}0& x=0\\ |x|^{\lambda}\cdot \sin\frac{1}{x} & x\neq 0 \end{cases}$
>
> a) is differentiable in zero
>
> b) has a continuous derivative in zero.

### My try

a)
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{|h|^{\lambda}}{h} \cdot \sin\frac{1}{h} = 0$$

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{|h|^{\lambda}}{h} \cdot \sin\frac{1}{h} = 0$$
But there I have some doubts. It seems like $\lambda$ does not matter there....

Moreover, can somebody give me hints to b)? 
 I think that I have do the same thing but this is unbelievable

Comment: Do you think the first limit exists if $\lambda = 1/2?$

Comment: No, it cannot exists - Does mean that $\lambda - 1 > 0 $ ?

Comment: and in the second case we have the same situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the existence part, to make sure the limit $$ f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\ \frac{|h|^{\lambda}}{h}\sin\frac{1}{h} $$ exists, we have $ \lambda>1 $. And the limit is $ 0 $.

For the continuous derivative part, we have to let the following limit equal to $ 0 $, i.e. :
$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\ f'(h)-f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\ f'(h)-0=\lim_{h\to 0}\ f'(h)=0 .$$
Thus, $$ \begin{align} \lim_{h\to 0+}f'(h)&= \lim_{h\to 0+}\left[(\lambda-1)h^{\lambda-2}\sin\frac{1}{h}-h^{\lambda-3}\cos\frac{1}{h}\right]=0 \end{align} $$
and
$$ \begin{align} \lim_{h\to 0-}f'(h)&= -\lim_{h\to 0-}\left[(-\lambda+1)(-h)^{\lambda-2}\sin\frac{1}{h}-(-h)^{\lambda-3}\cos\frac{1}{h}\right]=0 \end{align} .$$
Therefore, $ \lambda> 3 $.

Comment: $ \lambda> 3 $ - are you sure about that part? I think that there should be $ \lambda> 2 $

Comment: @VirtualUser Yes, since $ \cos\frac{1}{h} $ does not exist.